Using php for form-handling in astro
I am wondering if you can use PHP for form handling in Astro?
The only resource I could find for form handling in Astro is an example from their reference page, where they build a registration form
But is it possible to use php to let the form send an email to me instead? How would I have to implement that?

What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you have any specific question about this problem?

I reached that solution using hosting goddady and creating a php file with the mail logic in the root of cpanel, and my astro project I make a react component form to manage that request targeting that PHP file

I also used this method on a website! Just put a PHP file into the public folder and call it from a form. Our cPanel uses apache (I think), so the PHP file just gets called automatically. The astro dev command will not work tho. Bit of a testing in production, but can be done

No. Astro is written in JavaScript, not PHP. That means you'll need to write server-side logic in JavaScript as well.
For general form building, see e.g. Build HTML forms in Astro pages. This will require either server or hybrid mode.
On the other hand, if you just want an email sent, you can stick to using Astro's static site generation mode and use something like Netlify email integration (if you're hosting on Netlify) or just Google Forms.

Thank you for your answer. The form building itself is not a problem, but I need the action so that when someone clicks the submit button, the content is sent to me via email. Is there any plain code possibility without using third-party services like Netlify and Co.?

yes, obviously the Astro docs I linked cover not only the form itself but also what happens on submission.
